# GraphQL: Subscription not firing when mutation run

Tags: graphql, graphcool

So, I'm testing subscriptions on Graphcool and would appreciate some clarification on how exactly they work.

I have a one to many relationship from Posts on Comments:

Schema

```html
type Posts {
  caption: String!
  comments: [Comments!]! @relation(name: "PostsOnComments")
  createdAt: DateTime!
  displaysrc: String!
  id: ID!
  likes: Int
  updatedAt: DateTime!
}

type Comments {
  createdAt: DateTime!
  id: ID!
  posts: Posts @relation(name: "PostsOnComments")
  text: String!
  updatedAt: DateTime!
  user: String!
}
```

The subscription I run in Graphcool is as follows:

```html
subscription CreatedDeletedComments {
 Comments(
    filter: {
      mutation_in: [CREATED, DELETED]
    }
  ) {
    mutation
    node {
      id
      user
      text
    }
  }
}
```

If I run the following in my React app, a created notification is fired:

```html
    return this.props.client.mutate({
      mutation: gql`
        mutation createComment ($id: ID, $textVal: String!, $userVal: String!) {
          createComments (postsId: $id, text: $textVal, user: $userVal){
            id
            text
            user
          }
        }
      `,
      variables: {
        "id": postID,
        "textVal": textVal,
        "userVal": userVal
       },
      // forceFetch: true,
    })
```

But if I run the following, no deleted notification is fired:

```html
    return this.props.client.mutate({
      mutation: gql`
        mutation removeComment ($id: ID!, $cid: ID!) {
          removeFromPostsOnComments (postsPostsId: $id, commentsCommentsId: $cid){
            postsPosts {
              id
              displaysrc
              likes
              comments {
                id
                text
                user
              }
            }
          }
        }
      `,
      variables: {
        "id": postID,
        "cid": commentID
       },
      // forceFetch: true,
    })
```

What am I overlooking here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the subscription

```
subscription CreatedDeletedComments {
    Comments(
    filter: {
      mutation_in: [CREATED, DELETED]
    }
  ) {
    mutation
    node {
      id
      user
      text
    }
  }
}
```

you are subscribing to *comment nodes being created or deleted*. However, with the mutation `removeFromPostsOnComments`, you are not deleting any comment nodes. Instead, you are only deleting the *connection* between a post and a comment.

You can adjust your mutation request to delete the comment entirely instead of disconnecting it from the post:

```
return this.props.client.mutate({
  mutation: gql`
    mutation removeComment ($cid: ID!) {
      deleteComment(id: $cid) {
        id
      }
    }
  `,
  variables: {
    "cid": commentID
   },
  // forceFetch: true,
})
```

If you don't want to delete the comment entirely but still want to hide it in your app, you could have a boolean field `deleted` that acts as a soft deletion marker.

Then you could subscribe to `UPDATED` comments instead of `DELETED` comments and check if the field `deleted` was updated. Refer to [the 
 docs](https://www.graph.cool/docs/reference/simple-api/subscribing-to-updated-nodes-ohmeta3pi4/) for more information on how to do that with  `updatedFields`.

Subscriptions for relations is also already [part of our roadmap](https://github.com/graphcool/feature-requests/issues/146).

Comment: Perfect. The only issue I'm having with deleteComments, is in relation to my UI, reactive cache, not updating to reflect the change. How do I refactor updateQueries (See my updated question) to work with `this.props.client.mutate` (I'm triggering from an onClick event), as my root_query (as depicted in Apollo devTools), is `allPostses`?

Comment: Could you post a separate question for that? In general, it seems that using `update` is recommended vs. using `updateQueries` nowadays anyway.

Comment: Sure. New question submitted.

Comment: Is there a technical reason why removeFromPostsOnComments doesn't actually delete the comment node?

Comment: There's a difference between removing the connection between two nodes (`removeFromPostsOnComments` in this case) and deleting a node. Sometimes you need one of the two, sometimes you need both. So having the atomic operations available makes sense and still allows you  :)