# GraphQL error: Unknown argument 'deleted' on field 'removeFromPostsOnComments'

Tags: graphql, graphcool

So, I have a one to many relationship from Posts to comments:

```html
type Comments {
  createdAt: DateTime!
  deleted: Boolean
  id: ID!
  posts: Posts @relation(name: "PostsOnComments")
  text: String!
  updatedAt: DateTime!
  user: String!
}

type Posts {
  caption: String!
  comments: [Comments!]! @relation(name: "PostsOnComments")
  createdAt: DateTime!
  displaysrc: String!
  id: ID!
  likes: Int
  updatedAt: DateTime!
}
```

and wish to run a mutation, which as well as deleting the connection between a post and a comment, attempts to update the field 'deleted, on Comments, to true:

```html
mutation removeComment ($id: ID!, $cid: ID!, $stateB: Boolean) {
  removeFromPostsOnComments (postsPostsId: $id, commentsCommentsId: $cid, deleted: $stateB){
    postsPosts {
      __typename
      id
      comments {
        __typename
        id
        text
        user
        deleted
        posts {
          __typename
          id
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
  
Query Variables

{
  "id": "cj0qkl04vep8k0177tky596og",
  "cid": "cj1de905k8ya201934l84c3id"
}
```

But when I run the mutation I get the following error message:

```html
GraphQL error: Unknown argument 'deleted' on field 'removeFromPostsOnComments' of type 'Mutation'. (line 2, column 74):
  removeFromPostsOnComments(postsPostsId: $id, commentsCommentsId: $cid, deleted: $stateB) {
```

As was explained to me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43242475/graphql-subscription-not-firing-when-mutation-run), only the link between Posts and comments is deleted, not the actual 'Comment' record itself. So my thinking is, as the record is not deleted, why can I not update the 'deleted' field?

I wish to do this so that it triggers a subscription, which is monitoring the [updated](https://www.graph.cool/docs/reference/simple-api/subscribing-to-updated-nodes-ohmeta3pi4/#subscribe-to-updated-fields) field 'deleted'.

The generated mutation output is as follows:

```html
  "data": null,
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Unknown argument 'deleted' on field 'removeFromPostsOnComments' of type 'Mutation'. (line 2, column 77):\n    removeFromPostsOnComments (postsPostsId: $id, commentsCommentsId: $cid, deleted: $stateB){\n                                                                            ^",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 77
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

As can be seen in the image, 'deleted' is definitely included in 'Comments' my GraphCool schema:

[image]

Comment: How does your mutation look like on the server?

Comment: @Locco0_0 If you mean what does the generated output of running the mutation look like, please see my amended question.

Comment: The GraphQL Error suggests that you did not add the deleted argument to the mutation on the server

Comment: @Locco0_0 As can be seen on the attached image, see amended question, 'deleted' is definitely added to 'Comments'part of my GraphCool schema. Possibly a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I reproduced your issue. First of all, you're getting the error message because `deleted` is not part of the arguments of  the `removeFromPostsOnComments`-mutation, you also see that in the docs:

[image]

If you want to update the `deleted` field on the `Comments` type, you have to use the `updateComments`-mutation:

```
mutation {
  updateComments(id: "cj1de905k8ya201934l84c3id", deleted: true) {
    id
  }
}
```